# Why the request ID of AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest is always increase progressively?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

[image]First, I create a playItem A, and I could see the request ID is 1 to 2. Then I destroy the A, and create a another playItem B, I see the request ID is 3 to 4. Why the request ID could be increase between two different playItem.

Comment: where is the request ID?

Comment: I have submit a picture, you can see the red circle.